# How do I make git understand that its "push" has failed? Git push failed. Cannot add files to a commit now.

Tags: git, github, git-push

I want to re-add, re-commit, and re-push everything.
Git thinks it's pushed out to the remote repository, but somehow it failed.

Below are the steps I've gone through and the results.
0. create remote git repository in github.com
1. git init
    In  my working directory

2. git add .
3. git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myfiles
4. git push -u origin master
   -FAIL. HTTP error (I don't have the exact language for it)

Now, when I run "git status" I get nothing. It seems to think that I've "pushed" everything, but it's not there in Github.

I've checked the .ignore and .exclude files.

I want to re-add, re-commit, and re-push everything.

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   Test file/ file

 Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)


 Untracked files:
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Just `git push -u origin master` again

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. It returned that everything was up-to-date, but my git folder is still completely empty.

Comment: It worked. I took out the "-u" and everything is now up-to-date. Any idea why that might have been the lynch pin?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea why that might have been the lynch pin?

Considering the status you mention in the question, the file(s) was(were) not added to the index, or the commit was not done (considering it is missing between step 2 and 3)

If the first commit is missing, you cannot push anything to remote (`push -u` or not): you would be pushing 0 commit.

Once you manage to make at least one commit, the push can proceed.

Comment: It sounds like what you are saying that, if I later on "git push" after I've made some changes and added them, it will update all of the files that should have been "pushed" before EVEN IF those old files (that should have been pushed) had not been added?

Comment: @Android102 no, the main point is the commit part: changing and adding isn't enough. You need to have made at least one commit for the push to push anything.